# Unable to send mail through node mailer. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED at port 25"

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, nodemailer

Every time I make a forgot password request, it gives me this error and the mail is never sent to the Mailtrap.

[image: Please have a look at postman post screenshot.]

**Nodemailer Setup**
This is the basic node mailer setup I did.

port = 25

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const sendEmail = async (options) => {
  // 1) Create a Transporter
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  // 2) Define the email Options
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'Sachin Yadav <sachin.yadav@gmail.com',
    to: options.email,
    subject: options.subject,
    text: options.text,
  };

  // 3) Send the email
  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
};
```

**Forgot Password Function**

**catchAsync** is just a wrapper function which is created just to catch asynchronous errors separately. It returns the async function passed into it and call it with the req, res and next parameters.

```
exports.forgotPassword = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // 1) Get user based on posted email
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

  if (!user)
    return next(
      new AppError('No user with that email. Please try again!', 404)
    );

  // 2) Generate Random
  const resetToken = user.createPasswordResetToken();
  await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

  // 3) Send back the token on email
  const resetURL = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/api/v1/users/resetPassword/${resetToken})}`;

  const message = `Forgot your password? Submit a PATCH request with your new password and passwordConfirm to : ${resetURL}`;

  // Send Email
  try {
    await sendEmail({
      email: user.email,
      subject: 'Password reset link (Valid for 10mins)',
      message,
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      message: 'Token send',
    });

    // Err
  } catch (err) {
    // Set back the token and expire time
    user.createPasswordResetToken = undefined;
    user.passwordResetExpires = undefined;
    await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

    return next(
      new AppError(`There was an error sending the email ${err.message}`, 500)
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the port from 25 to 2525 and for some reason it worked. If anyone know why this worked, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be some other application is using port '25' in your system. If you're using a Windows PC you can check the ports that are being used with the below command(you need to open cmd as an administrator):

> netstat -aon

[image]